# Rounded chair seat

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

[image]

I try to round off the corners of the chair seat by CTRL + B, but I can not. Similarly, the Surface modifier Subdivision.

Comment: Try removing doubles before bevelling. Also the seat seems largely symmetrical, consider using the correct half erasing the other one then using a Mirror modifier

Comment: I use mirror modifier, half chair seat and work.

Comment: Your model has possibly disconnected or even double faces. Hard to tell with just a picture to look at. You might want to upload your file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then post the given link into your question.